# Magento 2 / Clear cache from another server

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

We have the project on 2 servers. Is there a way to programmatically clear cache for both servers?

I tried apply clear cache on 2 servers with [this method](https://magepow.com/blog/how-to-use-auto-flush-cache-on-magento-2/) but it does not work

And change event with *catalog_product_save_after* I tried modifying a field in some products, but the changes are only reflected in 1 server.

I have seen solutions such as creating a file in the root and placing the cache cleaning functionality to run from a url, or running a cron every so often to run the cache cleaning for the other server. I would like to know if there is a way to clear cache towards the other server programmatically?